# Loading images into memory in iPhone App

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an  `UImageView` and on click of an button i want to change the `UImage` in the `UImageView`. App has 22 `UImages` with each image exceeding 5 mb size , so the `UImageView` takes some time to load an image when the button is clicked , is there a way by which we can load these images into the memory so that image view takes lesser time to show the image?

**I use the following code to set the image :**

```
 [ImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName.jpg"]];
```

basically i want on swipe the images to be changed , e.g. if a user swipes from right to left the app must show the next image and on left to right click the back image be loaded . please suggest .

Comment: maybe you can tell us how you solved the problem or mark the right solution if its already included

Answer (score 1):

like @Gobot mentioned it is the best way du reduce the size of your pictures. For the swipe there is no need to use big pictures like this. You could just create two folders, one with small sized pictures and another with bigger one. If you swipe through, you just use the small pictures. If a user taps a picture you could get the name of the selected `UIImage` and load just this single picture. That way you also can provide high quality pictures for zooming in. And keep in mind, that your app package gets also bigger the more pictures you have included.

There is a good explanation in a WWDC Stream: [iOS App Performance: Graphics and Animations](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=238)

I also created a method inside a `NSMutableArray` category for loading all my `UIImages` once. You could use this method inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getImagesWithStartSuffix:(NSString *)start 
                                andEndSuffix:(NSString *)end{

    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 1; i < 100 + 2; i++) {

        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d%@.jpg", 
                                        start, i, end];

        if([self fileExistsInProject:fileName]){

            [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:fileName]];
        } else {

            break;
        }
    }
    return imageArray;
}
```

There is also a very easy way to change the size of your pictures by writing an `Apple Script`. You could run a loop over all pictures and resize them all this way. This is the easiest way and you don't have to use any tools like `Gimp` or `PS`:

```
do shell script "sips [path_to_file]/picture1.jpg -z 666 1000 --out [path]/changedSize/picture1_small.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Documentation:

> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching image object is not already in the cache, this method loads the image data from the specified file, caches it, and then returns the resulting object.

if it takes too long, you may want to add a progress indicator in your app till the full view is generated/loaded then display it on your screen.

Comment: can not we load the images into the cache ?

Comment: you can't have direct access to the cache, its system controlled. and neither can u clear it manually. (thats why this method is not advised in some cases, but not your case)
can you provide more info on what you are trying to do maybe I can help you with a different way to reach your goal

Comment: i have two buttons say next and back , when the user presses the next button the next image is to be displayed in the image view and the when the back button is presses the previous image is to be displayed . i have maintained a counter variable to track the image to be displayed in the image view.

Comment: what you can do, is preload the next and previous images (if they exist) or better even just the next image, since the previous image might be already cached and will be loaded quickly. So have 2 UIImageViews one always loaded with the next one and swap between them. if there is still a hiccup in the app load the hidden UIView in a method called by – performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: and a delay of like 0.1

Comment: the method imagenamed caches the images into the memory so for heavy images it is not recommendable , instead i am now using the method image imagewithcontentsoffile to set the image into UIimageView and its working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

The first and simplest option would be to reduce your images under 5MB. Do they really need to be that big? Are they thumbnails? The more complex option would be to load/cache images in a background thread (asynchronously) using dispatch queues.